# Разбить список на части

Tags: c#

Каким образом можно разбить список на n количество частей? Для примера есть List в нем 1400 записей, каким образом мне его разбить на, припустим, 3 списка по 466 записей?

Comment: На вскидку используя linq и из него Skip() и Take() ?)

Comment: Если у вас последний .NET, то [.Chunk()](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.chunk). Если нет, то стандартное решение примерно такое: `.Select((x, i) => (Index: i, Value: x)).GroupBy(x => x.Index / размер).Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value))`, ну или сами проходитесь по списку, пропуская (`.Skip()`) лишнее и забирая (`.Take()`) нужное. Еще вариант есть через `Range`, там суть примерно аналогичная, проходитесь сами, забирая определенный "срез".

Comment: Разбить то можно, а зачем?

Comment: @aepot есть массив данных который нужно передать по сети. На каждый элемент будет получен ответ. Выяснили (опытным путём), что отправлять можно не более 100 штук - надо разбить на мелкие массивы по 100. Если больше - сервак не успевает обработать массив.

Comment: Нашел несколько вариантов решения https://www.techiedelight.com/ru/split-a-list-into-sublists-of-size-n-in-csharp/